# Annotating Custom React Hook With TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have a custom React Hook that watches for a click outside of a specific element. It works just fine, but I am having trouble making TypeScript happy in a few places.

**App.js**

```
import { useRef, useCallback } from "react";
import useClick from "./useClick";

export default function App() {
  const asideRef = useRef(null);

  const handleStuff = useCallback(() => {
    console.log("a click outside of the sidebar occurred.");
  }, []);

  useClick(asideRef, handleStuff);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <aside ref={asideRef}>
        <nav>
          <ul></ul>
        </nav>
      </aside>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**useClick.js**

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

const useClick = (ref: React.MutableRefObject<HTMLElement>, cb: () => void) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const checkClick = (e: React.MouseEvent): void => {
      if (ref.current && !ref.current.contains(e.target as Node)) {
        cb();
      }
    };

    document.addEventListener("click", checkClick);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("click", checkClick);
    };
  }, [ref, cb]);
};

export default useClick;
```

**The first problem area** is in `App.js`, where the `useClick` hook is called. TypeScript complains about the first parameter passed to `useClick` and gives a message of:

```
Argument of type 'MutableRefObject<null>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MutableRefObject<HTMLElement>'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'HTMLElement'.ts(2345)
```

I know this has something to do with me setting the initial value of the ref to null, and the argument for the ref in `useClick` being annotated as `React.MutableRefObject<HTMLElement>`. I just don't know how to fix it.

**The second problem area** is in `useClick.js`, where the event listeners are added and removed. TypeScript seems to have a problem with my `checkClick` function. The error is so long that I have no choice but to show a photo of it below.

If anyone has any idea's on how to fix these two issues, so TypeScript will be happy, the help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Hi, this is very nicely documented, but do you mind reposting this as two separate questions with specific error information in the titles? "Omnibus" posts to help with various problems in your program are not allowed here, and I flagged this question for closure for that reason.

Comment: @Noah It does seem that way, but the problems involved are actually related.

Comment: What version of React are you using, Dan?

Comment: 17.0.2 Here's a codesandbox where you can actually see the errors yourself. https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-meitner-34mn7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi Dan: I'll start with what needs to change, then explain why below. (I also renamed your TypeScript file extensions to reflect their content.)

`useClick.ts`

Before:

```ts
// ...
const useClick = (ref: React.MutableRefObject<HTMLElement>, cb: () => void) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const checkClick = (e: React.MouseEvent): void => {
// ...
```

After:

```ts
// ...
const useClick = (ref: React.RefObject<HTMLElement>, cb: () => void) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const checkClick = (e: MouseEvent): void => {
// ...
```

---

`App.tsx`

Before:

```ts
export default function App() {
  const asideRef = useRef(null);
```

After:

```ts
export default function App() {
  const asideRef = useRef<HTMLElement>(null);
```

---

First, let's address the `checkClick` function: This function signature should be assignable to the `EventListener` type in `lib.dom.d.ts`:

```ts
interface EventListener {
    (evt: Event): void;
}
```

Because your parameter is `React.MouseEvent`, which does not extend the native `Event`, type, it is incompatible. Just use the native `MouseEvent` type instead, since you're adding the listener to the document (which has nothing to do with React anyway.)

Next, let's look at the function signature for `useClick`:

You might want to reference the type definitions for `useRef` while reading this part:

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/5149827c1f97541dd69d950039b83ace68e119e6/types/react/index.d.ts#L1025-L1063

The first parameter is the only one that needs to change, and it needs to change from a `MutableRefObject` to a `RefObject`. The difference between these can be subtle, but there are some great resources you can read to learn more about them. Here's one, for example:

https://dev.to/wojciechmatuszewski/mutable-and-immutable-useref-semantics-with-react-typescript-30c9

When creating a ref that you pass to React to use for an element reference, you should provide `null` as the initial argument to `useRef` (which you did) and also provide a generic type annotation for the type of value it should hold (in this case it's `HTMLElement`). When using a ref for a DOM element, React expects that you will never mutate this ref since it's being controlled by React, so the type that is returned by `useRef` in this case is simply a `RefObject`. Therefore, that's what you should use for the first parameter of `useClick`.